# Flutter Navigator pass a class as arguments, can't get arguments properties, but method?

Tags: flutter, arguments, navigator

How to use Flutter Navigator to pass a class as an argument with all properties and methods?  In my code below, I passed a class instance "dataClass" with four properties and two methods as shown below.

```
bool _bGender;
int _bWeight;
double _bHeight;
int _bAge;

double getBMI();
String getDiagnose();
```

In the 2nd screen, "resultpage.dart", I was able to receive the argument(dataClass), but there is no properties found, only method. Not sure why?

```
args._bAge (Not found)
args._bWeight (Not found)
args._bHeight (Not found)
args._bGender (Not found)
args.getBMI() Ok!
args.getDiagnose() Ok!
```

*BTW, this is a complete and functional Flutter App, BMI Calculator without error*

**File name: main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'resultpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// Data class used to pass args to result page
class BMIdata {
  bool _bGender;
  int _bWeight;
  double _bHeight;
  int _bAge;

  BMIdata(this._bGender, this._bWeight, this._bHeight, this._bAge);

  double getBMI() {
    return this._bWeight / (this._bHeight/100 * 2);
  }

  String getDiagnose(double bmi) {
    String _diagnose;

    //Body Mass Index (BMI)
    //Source: https://www.cdc.gov/obesity/adult/defining.html
    //Source 2: https://depart.femh.org.tw/dietary/3OPD/BMI.htm
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
      _diagnose = 'Underweight';
    } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.0) {
      _diagnose = 'Healthy!';
    } else if (bmi > 24.0 && bmi < 27.0) {
      _diagnose = 'Overweight';
    } else if (bmi > 27.0 && bmi < 30.0) {
      _diagnose = 'Slightly Obese';
    } else if (bmi > 30.0 && bmi < 35.0) {
      _diagnose = 'Obesity';
    } else if (bmi > 35.0) {
      _diagnose = 'Server Obesity';
    }

    return _diagnose;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter BMI Calculator',
      theme: ThemeData(
//          primaryColor: Colors.black87,
          ),
      home: Calculator(),
      routes: {
        '/resultPage': (context) => ResultPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Calculator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalculatorState createState() => _CalculatorState();
}

class _CalculatorState extends State<Calculator> {
  var dataClass = BMIdata(false, 55, 160, 25); //initial value

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          title: Center(
            child: Text('BMI Calculator'),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              dataClass._bGender = true;
                              print(dataClass._bGender);
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                                    color: dataClass._bGender
                                        ? Colors.white
                                        : Colors.grey.shade800,
                                    size: 80,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'FEMALE',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: dataClass._bGender
                                            ? Colors.white
                                            : Colors.grey.shade800,
                                        fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              dataClass._bGender = false;
                              print(dataClass._bGender);
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                                    color: dataClass._bGender
                                        ? Colors.grey.shade700
                                        : Colors.white,
                                    size: 80,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'MALE',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: dataClass._bGender
                                            ? Colors.grey.shade700
                                            : Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'Height',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      dataClass._bHeight.toString() + ' cm',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Slider(
                      min: 60,
                      max: 240,
                      value: dataClass._bHeight,
                      divisions: 240 - 60,
                      label: dataClass._bHeight.round().toString(),
                      activeColor: Colors.red,
                      inactiveColor: Colors.white24,
                      onChanged: ((double value) {
                        setState(() {
                          dataClass._bHeight = value;
                          print(value);
                        });
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              'Weight',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              dataClass._bWeight.toString(),
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 60),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: 50.0,
                                height: 50.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                ),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        dataClass._bWeight -= 1;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 50.0,
                                height: 50.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                ),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        dataClass._bWeight += 1;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              'Age',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              dataClass._bAge.toString(),
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 60),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: 50.0,
                                height: 50.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                ),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        dataClass._bAge -= 1;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    onLongPress: (){
                                      setState(() {
                                        dataClass._bAge -= 10;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 50.0,
                                height: 50.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                ),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        dataClass._bAge += 1;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    onLongPress: (){
                                      setState(() {
                                        dataClass._bAge += 10;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              width: _screenWidth * .9,
              height: _screenHeight * .1,
              child: FlatButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  'Calculate BMI',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    ResultPage.routeName,
                    arguments: dataClass,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**File name: resultPage.dart**

```
import 'package:bmiflutterapp/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/resultPage';

  @override
  _ResultPageState createState() => _ResultPageState();
}

class _ResultPageState extends State<ResultPage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BMIdata args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;


    print(args.getDiagnose(args.getBMI()));


    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('BMI Calculating Result:'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Your BMI is " +
                "${args.getBMI().toStringAsFixed(2)}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Diagnosis is "+
                "${args.getDiagnose(args.getBMI())}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I finally figured out!  After I removed "_" under lines from instance properties, I could access all instance properties!  

args._bAge  => args._bAge, 
args._bWeight => args._bWeight, 
args._bHeight => args._bHeight, 
args._bGender => args._bGender

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure but maybe it's due to the fact that your properties are private.
So, you find it yourself :)

Comment: @FPerroch Yeah, I agreed that's what had happen. Thanks!